# FastText: upper case or lower case

Tags: nlp, uppercase, lowercase, fasttext

Using the pre-trained model:

```
import fasttext.util
fasttext.util.download_model('en', if_exists='ignore')  # English
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
```

both queries `ft['HOME']` and `ft['home']` works, but return different vectors.

What is the optimal query to make?

If I'm working with an uppercased corpus, should I transform it into a lowercased?